# How to vectorize a matrix variable in CVXPY?

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I can create a symmetric matrix variable in CVXPY with `X = cp.Variable((size_n, size_n), symmetric=True)`. Is there a way to vectorize the matrix so that I can obtain a size_n*size_n by 1 vector?

I want to do this because I want to calculate the result of a linear operator A that acts on this matrix, which is left by multiplying A with this vectorized matrix vector.

For instance, I want to minimize `cvxpy.norm(A @ vec(X))`. However, I cannot find such a vectorization function. I am not sure how to code it up by myself either.

It is possible to just create a new vector variable and append size_n * size_n constraints setting each entry of the matrix equal to the vector. However, this doesn't seem to be a very elegant way to do this and I'm afraid it will affect the performance.

Comment: perhaps its just me, but I find this quite confusing.  Suggest you mock up a small example for like `n=3` showing what you intend to do with code or math.

Comment: @AirSquid I have edited it, does it help? Here is vectorization in mathematics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)

Comment: This is not really vectorizing, is it?  You just want to add a third dimension.

Comment: https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.affine.html#cvxpy.vec I found what I need, maybe I will type out an answer.

Comment: @wsz_fantasy When you find some time, please do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the vectorization function, it is contained in the cvxpy library.
See [here](https://cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.affine.html#cvxpy.vec).

By inspecting its code, it can be observed that it in essence uses the reshape function.